# Local Instance of Django/Feincms not working

Tags: django, heroku, feincms

I have installed a customer Heroku/Django application locally (Windows 7 machine) to make some modifications and the system uses Feincms and I can't get the pages that utilize it to work. For instance one template page contains the following

```
{% feincms_render_region feincms_page "main" request %}
```

But nothing is loaded when I access the local application. The live application is working fine so I guess there is something odd/wrong with my installation. I am not getting any error and I have followed all of the installation instructions. It is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` and one of the `models.py` files registers the extension.

Anyone have any ideas on how to track down why nothing is loaded?

Comment: What does "nothing is loading" mean? Do you have blank pages or what else?

Comment: The Django template loads and is displayed but the feincms command does not appear to load the HTML it should.